# Passing Command line arguments to .exe generated after build

Tags: electron.net

I have a desktop App.exe built using Electron.Net. If I pass parameters along with "electronize start", these argument values are ignored. Even after build, I am not able to pass parameters as command line arguments to .exe from command prompt.

In command prompt, when I run App.exe with command line arguments it does not accept the parameters being passed to it. Only the const parameters - which are existing in main.js is available. Since main.js is getting auto-generated after each "electronize start", changes made in main.js get replaced. Sample command below:

Example: `App.exe hello 123
electronize start hello 123`

The requirement is to retrieve parameters given by the user in command prompt to .exe file. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please submit a Feature Request via Issue on the GitHub Page. **Thank you!**

https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET